# custom function doesn't respecting WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to create a function that returns a value from a table

```
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` FUNCTION  `GETINFO` (
    `INFO_ID` BIGINT( 20 ) ,
    `ENTITY` VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
    `ANCHOR` VARCHAR( 255 )
) RETURNS DOUBLE DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN DECLARE var_name DOUBLE;

    # default value
    SET var_name = -999.999;

    # get desired value in database
    SELECT MAX(`value`) 
        INTO var_name
        FROM  `mydata` 
        WHERE `info`   = INFO_ID
          AND `entity` = ENTITY
          AND `anchor` = ANCHOR 
        LIMIT 0 , 1;

    RETURN var_name;

    END
```

when I try to call the function:

```
case 1) SELECT GETINFO(2, "134604843861826", "uniq") <========= real parameters, works fine
case 2) SELECT GETINFO(2, "1346048438618",   "uniq") <========= just removed some chars to force error, but returns same value as case 1
case 3) SELECT GETINFO(12312, "123",         "1233") <========= all params incorrect, now it returns NULL as expected
```

**question** in case 2, why it doesn't respect the WHERE clause and return NULL?

Comment: I don't see the difference between case 1 and 2.

Comment: Why do you need the `LIMIT` clause? `MAX()` can only return 1 result.

Comment: I changed case 2 and removed only 2 chars to force error. this continues returning same as case 1

Comment: @fancyPants That's what he's expecting -- he says he _is_ getting a result when he expects `NULL`.

Comment: @fancyPants That's right. It's not returning NULL, and he wants to know why not.

Comment: That's because I also read the text next to the arrow in case 2, where it says "but returns same value as case 1". That additional context helped me parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem are these lines:

```
     AND `entity` = ENTITY
      AND `anchor` = ANCHOR
```

These do *nothing* in terms of filtering, because they both refer to columns in the table.  You should always prefix parameters in a function to avoid this problem.

```
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` FUNCTION  `GETINFO` (
    `param_INFO_ID` BIGINT( 20 ) ,
    `param_ENTITY` VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
    `param_ANCHOR` VARCHAR( 255 )
) RETURNS DOUBLE DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN DECLARE var_name DOUBLE;

    # default value
    SET var_name = -999.999;

    # get desired value in database
    SELECT MAX(`value`) 
        INTO var_name
        FROM  `mydata` 
        WHERE `info`   = param_INFO_ID
          AND `entity` = param_ENTITY
          AND `anchor` = param_ANCHOR 
        LIMIT 0 , 1;

    RETURN var_name;

    END
```

Comment: is it a problem prefix params just with underline? eg: _INFO_ID

Comment: @Leabdalla . . . Whatever you want to use is fine.  They should just be different from anything that might be a column name.